# OS native 2D API vs OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, opengl

Suppose I wanted to create a text editor from scratch.

I searched around and everyone suggested using OS-specific native 2D APIs (e.g. GDI+ in Windows or XLib in Linux), especially for font rendering.

My question is: why is it that openGL isn't suited for such a task? Why is it so hard to render antialiased text and controls as in a text editor with openGL and why should I prefer the non-portable way of native 2D OS APIs?

Comment: I don't see a reason to go OS-specific APIs on this one when you have things like Qt and GTK, to cite the most popular, that are cross-platform. I never used GTK but I know that Qt is very powerful and easy. Have a look on those before deciding to go GDI or Xlib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the difficulty is that OpenGL doesn't provide a font engine or any capabilities specifically for rendering text. In other words, it's not a matter of OpenGL being poorly suited to the rendering part of the task, just that OpenGL is missing a lot of pieces necessary to the task.

To render text under OpenGL, you'd typically start with some font engine to take (for example) a TrueType or OpenType font, and render a glyph from its info (e.g., FreeType). Then you need a text display engine to figure out how to render characters to display your strings decently. In a simple case like English, it has to handle things like kerning and leading. In a complex case like some Arabic scripts, you basically need kind of a feedback loop between the text rendering and the font rendering, because a glyph can take a different form depending on its context in the string.

In short, writing a text editor that renders its text via OpenGL means re-building a lot of a text rendering stack from the ground up.

If you don't care a lot about rendering quality, you might be able to get by with just rendering a few fonts to bitmaps, and displaying your text using them. This can simplify the code quite a bit, but a simple implementation will mean producing output that looks something like an MS-DOS command line. Even matching the output quality of, say, Windows 3.0 will take a fair amount of work. That's not to say it can't be done--but it could dwarf the difficulty of writing the editing part of the text editor.

Comment: Got it. For completeness' sake and leaving aside the text matter but still related to a text editor: any other downsides in using openGL rather than the abovementioned OS 2D APIs? I always felt openGL being quite limited for UI tasks

Comment: @Dean: Pretty much the same situation: OpenGL could do the necessary drawing, but you'd have to write all your own code for things like menus, tool-bars, widgets, etc. (or use something that's already been written, such as FLTK, of course).

Comment: So the reason why OpenGL UI interfaces aren't much used for desktop programs is mostly related to the font rendering issues?

Comment: Not exactly. Just that OpenGL is basically a low level drawing library/engine, and that GUI usually need much more features, and implementing them all from scratch is just huge amount of work to be done. In systems like Linux, basically, you have a GUI engine at top of OpenGL, because X windowing system uses the driver. There is just many megabytes of code between OpenGL and e.g. GTK.

Comment: Toolkits like GTK are the least of your worries, the text stack is (freetype is just a bit, you need unicode opentype shaping and bidi handling too). There are scores of toolkits on the market but aside from uniscribe (Microsoft), harfbuzz (FLOSS) and whatever adobe/apple use there are no other text engine able to handle unicode/opentype nuances properly. unicode and opentype are monster always-elvolving specs. And all of those use one form or another of low level acceleration (opengl or directx) on their platforms of choice.